# MySql Distinct Issues: Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-select-db

I want to select distinct of apps_user.imeino

My current SQL Query:

```
SELECT app.name,app.emailid,app.mobileno,app.imeino,img.id,img.approve_status,img.path 
FROM apps_user  app, apps_userimage img 
WHERE ((SELECT DISTINCT apps_user.imeino FROM apps_user) =img.imeino );
```

MySql Distinct Issues: Error Code:

> 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Fix your query so you use explicit `join` syntax.  Your query has way more problems than just the subquery.

Comment: rearrange what he ask, what current going, what problem to be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join

```
SELECT app.name,app.emailid,app.mobileno,app.imeino,img.id,img.approve_status,img.path 
FROM apps_user app
join apps_userimage img on app.imeino = img.imeino
```